# Meteor Angular 2: ngFor doesn't update when model is extended

Tags: meteor, angular

I've got the following scenario:

I load something from the database (meteor/mongo) e.g. with:

```
this.subscribe('cards', options, () => {
    this.cards = Cards.find({}, {sort: this.sortObject.get()});
}, true);
```

In the template I iterate over those items using `*ngFor="#card of cards"`

When I extend the object on some action, e.g.

```
this.cards.forEach((card:Card) => {
  card.distance = someValue;
});
```

the template doesn't get updated, i.e. when i use `{{card.distance}}`, it is not displayed.

Is it not possible to extend objects/lists subscribed to using meteor and angular 2?

Comment: try `this.cards=this.cards.slice();` after the `forEach`

Comment: thanks for the hint, I tried, but got the error `Property 'slice' does not exist on type 'Cursor...`

Comment: How can you iterate with `forEach` if it isn't an array?

Comment: It is a meteor/mongo cursor and apparantly has forEach but not slice

Comment: Does it have a `toArray()`. This might work then as well.

Comment: It has `count`, `fetch`, `forEach`, `map`, `observe` and `observeChanges`. `fetch` does indeed return an array (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch). The problem is, if I use `fetch` the list isn't updated in real time from the db anymore and the advantages of meteor are lost. Maybe the only solution is not to enhance the card Object, but make a separate cardMeta array?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Here is what I tried:

```
class Company {
  constructor(private name:string) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'contacts-list',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#company of companies">{{company.name}} - {{company.distance}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div (click)="update()">Update</div>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#company of rawCompanies">{{company.name}} - {{company.distance}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div (click)="updateRaw()">Update</div>
  `
})
export class ContactsList {
  constructor () {
    this.companies = [
      new Company('company 1'),
      new Company('company 2'),
      new Company('company 3'),
    ];

    this.rawCompanies = [
      { name: 'company 1' },
      { name: 'company 2' },
      { name: 'company 3' }
    ];
  }

  update() {
    this.companies.forEach((company:Company) => {
      company.name = company.name + 'a';
      company.distance = 'test';
    });
  }

  updateRaw() {
    this.rawCompanies.forEach((company) => {
      company.name = company.name + 'a';
      company.distance = 'test';
    });
  }
}
```

Both `update` and `rawUpdate` update the view... Is there something I missed?

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/86i8RHYrFfRnTMMoQ1lH?p=preview.

Comment: Yes I think there is something you missed: The problem is meteor + angular 2. Only Angular 2 works fine, I already tried that myself here https://plnkr.co/edit/caP31EQVRYwG3yEh8kTs?p=preview